# R - matching one value by combining values in a column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with two columns as below:

```
    Col1       Col2
1   7197.36    14.00
2        NA  5173.94
3        NA 13333.06
4   7004.38   473.32
5        NA  4980.61
6  26355.52   110.05
7        NA  1307.32
8        NA  6531.06
9        NA  3777.65
10       NA  7827.44
11  8753.22    85.00
12       NA     1.86
13       NA  2009.42
14       NA   502.89
15       NA  3182.86
16       NA       NA
```

I wanted to find matching rows in column 'Col2' corresponding to the single value in 'Col1'.
For example, 7197.36 = 14.00 + 5173.94 + 2009.42 (rows 1,2,13 in 'Col2')

Here, sum of 'Col1' = sum of 'Col2'

The final data frame should look like this:

```
   Col1    Col2
 1   7197.36    14.00
 2        NA  5173.94
 3        NA  2009.42
 4   7004.38   473.32
 5        NA  6531.06
 6  26355.52   110.05
 7        NA  1307.32
 8        NA 13333.06
 9        NA  3777.65
10       NA  7827.44
11  8753.22    85.00
12       NA     1.86
13       NA  4980.61
14       NA   502.89
15       NA  3182.86
16       NA       NA
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Updated the question with expected data frame.

Answer (score 7):

We solve it via integer linear programming solving the problem of finding the minimum objective value greater than or equal to the target and if it is found to within numerical precision then return it; otherwise, return NULL.

```
library(lpSolve)

obj <- na.omit(DF$Col2)
targets <- na.omit(DF$Col1)
L <- lapply(targets, function(value) {
    iobj <- 100 * obj
    ivalue <- 100 * value
    res <- lp("min", iobj, t(iobj), ">=", ivalue, all.bin = TRUE)
    ok <- isTRUE(all.equal(ivalue, res$objval))
    if (ok) obj[res$solution == 1]
})
names(L) <- targets
```

giving:

```
> L

$`7197.36`
[1]   14.00 5173.94 2009.42

$`7004.38`
[1]  473.32 6531.06

$`26355.52`
[1] 13333.06   110.05  1307.32  3777.65  7827.44

$`8753.22`
[1] 4980.61   85.00    1.86  502.89 3182.86
```

**Note 1:** Later the question was modified to request this form of output:

```
transform(stack(L), Col1 = ifelse(duplicated(ind), NA, as.numeric(paste(ind))), 
                    Col2 = values)[3:4]
```

**Note 2:** We used this as `DF`

```
Lines <- "    Col1       Col2
1   7197.36    14.00
2        NA  5173.94
3        NA 13333.06
4   7004.38   473.32
5        NA  4980.61
6  26355.52   110.05
7        NA  1307.32
8        NA  6531.06
9        NA  3777.65
10       NA  7827.44
11  8753.22    85.00
12       NA     1.86
13       NA  2009.42
14       NA   502.89
15       NA  3182.86
16       NA       NA"

DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: This is near perfect solution. Why 26355.52 is not found. As such, all elements for this value are there in Col2: $`26355.52`
110.05  1307.32 13333.06  3777.65  7827.44.

Comment: OK. Good catch. Have fixed.

Comment: How can it be modified to find a close match? I mean target may or may not have exact match with obj vector but can it return the elements with close?

Comment: Try `ok <- (res$objval - ivalue) < 100 * eps` where you replace `eps` with whatever maximum difference is acceptable.

Comment: Is there any way to use the lp function once for all the elements in target vector? I mean I am looking to use each elements in 'obj' vector once in this process. For example, I have `obj <- c(1,4,5,3,6)` & `target <- c(8,11)`. Using this solution, I am getting `$8 [1] 5 3 $11 [1] 5 6`. Actually I am expecting `$8 [1] 1 4 3 $11 [1] 5 6` or `$8 [1] 5 3 $11 [1] 1 4 6`.

Comment: This is substationally different although it could still be solved by integer linear programming.   You might try to formulate it yourself as an integer programming problem and only if you really can't do it post it as a separate problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way using `combinations` from `gtools` *(Won't be very efficient for huge data sets)*

```
library(gtools)
library(zoo)
library(splitstackshape)

data$Col1_mod = na.locf(data$Col1)

df = stack(
     lapply(split(data, f = data$Col1_mod), 
     function(x){ 
         tmp1 = data.frame(
                combinations(
                    length(data$Col2[!is.na(data$Col2)]),
                    length(x$Col2[!is.na(x$Col2)]),
                    data$Col2[!is.na(data$Col2)]));
         tmp1$rowsums = rowSums(tmp1); 
         tmp2 = tmp1[tmp1$rowsums == unique(x$Col1_mod),];   
         toString(tmp2[,!colnames(tmp2) %in% 'rowsums'])
     }))
```

this will give

```
#> df
#                                       values      ind
#1                             473.32, 6531.06  7004.38
#2                        14, 2009.42, 5173.94  7197.36
#3          1.86, 85, 502.89, 3182.86, 4980.61  8753.22
#4 110.05, 1307.32, 3777.65, 7827.44, 13333.06 26355.52
```

you can reshape it using `cSplit` from `splitstackshape`

```
out = cSplit(setDT(df), 'values', ',', 'long')

 #>out
 #     values      ind
 #1:   473.32  7004.38
 #2:  6531.06  7004.38
 #3:    14.00  7197.36
 #4:  2009.42  7197.36
 #5:  5173.94  7197.36
 #6:     1.86  8753.22
 #7:    85.00  8753.22
 #8:   502.89  8753.22
 #9:  3182.86  8753.22
#10:  4980.61  8753.22
#11:   110.05 26355.52
#12:  1307.32 26355.52
#13:  3777.65 26355.52
#14:  7827.44 26355.52
#15: 13333.06 26355.52
```

Comment: This will probably become a huge mess for a bit bigger data set. Finding all combination is almost never a solution IMO

Comment: @DavidArenburg yes it is, I am trying to make it simpler if possible. But I liked G.Grothendieck's answer